# how to get the split value of the textbox

Tags: php, jquery

[image]

i am sorry. i am really don't know how to split that text-box `nama karyawan` value. i need that value to do a function for calling the data into textbox cost center, i need the value of the text-box `nama karyawan` value get split to do the where clause at the php.

someone who can help me.. please give me an example. it much better when using jquery

Comment: what do you want it to be split it with.? do you split it with `,` ?

Comment: you see at the Textbox Nama Karyawan has a value right?
`JOKO TRISNO, NURUDIN`. i need to make that value split into JOKO TRISNO and NURUDIN only . i need that to make a function for calling the database data that needed where clause with that textbox Nama Karyawan each value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In php:-

```
explode(",",$nama_karyawan_variable); //or use `" "`
```

Output:- https://eval.in/831835

In jQuery:-

```
$("id or class of that input").val().split(","); //or use `" "`
```

Example:-

```js
$('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
  console.log($("#nama_karyawan_variable").val().split(","));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="nama_karyawan_variable"><br/><br/>
<input type="button" value="Click me to get splited values!">
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can only help with jQuery -
(check this it will work for you) Cheers..!

```js
var myVal = $('.for_test').val().split(',');
console.log(myVal);
console.log(myVal[0]);
console.log(myVal[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Test, Content" class="for_test">
```

Comment: oh using an array for spliting that ?

Comment: Yes, I hope it helps.!

Comment: i will try the code 1st

Comment: @MinervazMine was it helpful.or you need anything more.?

Comment: still trying to figure it out in my code.

Comment: @MinervazMine what is the issue in your code.paste a fiddle so we can check.

Answer (score 1):

```
// exsample 1
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode (" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
```

---

```
// code
$textbox = $_POST["textbox"];
$ex_textbox = explode (" ", $textbox);
var_dump($ex_textbox);
```

php : http://php.net/manual/kr/function.explode.php

jquery : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

good day